# Find files with extensions consisting of numbers only

Tags: regex, bash, grep, find, ls

How could I find files ends with "log.[one or more digits of numbers]"?

I have a list of files in the log directory:

```
/user/log/log.1
/user/log/log.222
/user/log/log.201505
/user/log/log.2014.gz
```

I wanna gzip the files that ends with numbers only, and then move them to the bak directory:

```
/user/bak/log.1.gz
/user/bak/log.222.gz
/user/bak/log.201505.gz
```

Is there any way to include the pattern (log.[0-9]*) and exclude extensions other than numbers at the same time using **find** / **ls** / **grep** etc?

Also, my case requires me to perform the backup of logs above on other servers too, do I simply use

```
ssh $SERVER "command1;command2;..."
```

to do the job, even with loops?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-regex` flag to `find`. You'll probably also need `-E` to interpret the regex as a modern extended regex. Something like this:

```
find -E /user/log -regex '.*/log\.[0-9]+'
```

Comment: Sorry, turns out `-E` is from BSD find. If this works for you without it then great, otherwise you can look at [the `-regextype` flag](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Regular-Expressions).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the above command returns `find: unknown predicate `-E'`. It works fine without -E however. Could you mind explain a little bit more on what's .*/ before log in the regex?

Comment: @haust The regex has to match the entire path, which includes the `/user/log` prefix in this case. `.*/` says "match anything until the last slash". You could also just write `-regex '/user/log/log\.[0-9]+'` in this case.

Comment: The explanation is very clear, thank you. Would you mind answering the second part of the case too?

"Also, my case requires me to perform the backup of logs above on other servers too, do I simply use
`ssh $SERVER "command1;command2;..."`
to do the job, even with loops?"

Answer (score 1):

Using bash extended patterns:

```
shopt -s extglob
numeric_extensions=( *.+([0-9]) )          # use an array for storage
printf "%s\n" "${numeric_extensions[@]}"   # print the array contents
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a loop, here's an initiative:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /user/log/*; do
if [[ -f $file ]]; then
ext="${file##*.}"
if [[ $ext =~ [0-9]$ ]]; then
#only files with numeric extention are available here
#put your gzip or whateve code here
fi
fi
done
```

Comment: As I have to ssh into other servers and perform this action as well, I would like it to be simple and avoid loops if possible. Thanks for providing an alternate solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner you can use. I've tested for the execution locally.

```
find /user/log/ -type f -name "log.*[0-9]" -exec bash -c 'gzip "{}" && mv "{}.gz" "/user/bak/"' \;
```

You could possible invoke this using ssh as below:

```
ssh user@$SERVER 'find /user/log/ -type f -name "log.*[0-9]" -exec bash -c 'gzip "{}" && mv "{}.gz" "/user/bak/"' \;'
```

Comment: Neat solution except "log.*[0-9]" will include files like "log.a123" etc. I've combined your code with regex from @Ismail Badawi and it works fine.

`find /user/log/ -type f -regex '.*/log\.[0-9]+' -exec bash -c 'gzip "{}" && mv "{}.gz" "/user/bak/"' \;`

Thanks!

Comment: What would happen if there's no matching file, hence no file to gz and mv? Is there any way I could redirect the results (if any) to a log file?

Answer (score -1):

I came up with a similar regex:

```
^.+\/log\.[0-9]+
```